# Unable to install app on iOS 6.1

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5

I am facing a problem in installing ios app on the iphone with iOS 6.1. all the provisioning profiles and certificates works fine. App installed successfully on previous versions of iOS i.e.. 6.0.1, 5,4.
I am using testflight to download and install app on iPhone.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing same problem but i managed to install .ipa from xcode 4.5, so if you are less than that then kindly update you xcode version.

Comment: I am using 4.5.2 and made build with provisioning profile and now .ipa  is on the testflight . it can be installed on iPhone with ios 6.0.1 and 5 n 4 and its target is 4.3, but unable to download for the iphone with iOS 6.1.